# Laravel producing user statistics like DAUs and MAUs

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.7 with the built-in user authentication. I'd like to be able to produce metrics like daily and monthly active users.

I'll use an event listener on logins to save the data, but I'm wondering what the best practice for this is in terms of how to store information, as I'm struggling to find information or tutorials on this.

**Option 1: UserLogins table**

I was thinking about adding a table `UserLogins` with 2 columns: `user_id` and `login_date`. The latter would be a `DATETIME` column. Then every time a user logs in, a row is added to this table. From there I can produce the metrics.

The downside of this method is that over time the table can grow very large.

**Option 2: statistics table**

I already save the last_login_date for each user when they login. Using that, I could setup 2 scheduled processes to run daily and monthly. These processes calculate the DAUs and MAUs and save these stats in a table.

The downside of this method is that I won't have the raw data anymore. That data could be useful in the future.

I'm sure that there is are some best practices for this as many companies would need these metrics. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! It really depends on your use-case, but I'd probably go with **Option 1**.

Let's say you go with *Option 2* and have a `last_login_at` field in the users table.

Consider the following scenario: You have a new requirement from the marketing team. They want to know the locations the customers are logging in from, or maybe also the devices they are using.

You would need to save all the additional required information in the `users` table. You will also only be saving the last known metric and you will be relying on the cron jobs to possibly save this data elsewhere. It's not very scalable, if you think about it. Each time you need a new field, you would have to modify your cron jobs to cater for it.

Consider a second scenario. In applications that are of a sensitive nature, it would be good to raise a flag, for example, if you detect a login from a location you don't recognize. By saving all the login activities in a dedicated table, you can easily tell if the location has been changed from the last time the user has been logged in.

With **Option 1**, you can have a `user_logins` table that can keep track of all those information. Adding new fields won't be a pain as well. Queries/reporting on login activities will also be much easier since all these information reside in a single table.

Doing queries like Monthly Active Users and Daily Active Users can still perform well, with proper indexing etc. I have a similar set up at work and so far the table has grown to about a million rows and we never had any performance issues.